# How to get listener of a view

Tags: android, listener

I write service that interacts with other apps. It registers listeners on views (buttons, textviews,...), that already have listeners. I need to replace them with my own listeners (works), do some stuff and then unregister my listeners and restore the old ones.

1. An App with a button with an onClickListener is running
2. My service registers an onClickListener inside the UI-Thread + do something
3. My service restores the old listener

It would be easy, if there was a `view.getOnClickListener` -method. Then I could save the old ones and replace the new listeners when I'm done.

Is there any way to get listeners from a view or have more that one listener of the same type bound to one view?

```
Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            //do something
        }
    });
// I need to do, but found no solution for that.
View.OnClickListener oldListener = btn.getOnClickListener();
```

If I register the new listeners to a view, the old ones are overridden, right? It would be also okay if both listeners ("new" and "old") exist at the same time. Only the old ones must not be gone.

edit: Unfortunately I have no possibility to save the listener on assignment. I need to get it backwards from the view component.

Thanks

Comment: cant you just set your old listener by setOnClickListener method?
`setOnClickListener(old_listener);`

Comment: No because I don't know anything but the widgets of the app that the service "controls / hooks into (via instrumentation)". So I cannot save the old listener when it is assigned, because I have no src code of the app. With the instrumentation, I can get all widgets, buttons, etc but I also need the current active listeners. Hopefully this makes the problem more clear.

Comment: hi friend, did you achieve this ? i want to do the same thing @dr.AtZe

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Thanks to mihail's hint (thanks for that :)) )with the *hidden API*, I've found a solution to get a listener back after assignment:

The `android.view.View` class has a nested class `static class ListenerInfo` that stores all listeners on a View (API 14+). In older versions the listeners are private fields in the  `android.view.View`.

The field can be accessed with reflection. In my case (API 14+),

```
// get the nested class `android.view.View$ListenerInfo`
Field listenerInfoField = null;
listenerInfoField = Class.forName("android.view.View").getDeclaredField("mListenerInfo");
if (listenerInfoField != null) {
    listenerInfoField.setAccessible(true);
}
Object myLiObject = null;
myLiObject = listenerInfoField.get(myViewObj);

// get the field mOnClickListener, that holds the listener and cast it to a listener
Field listenerField = null;
listenerField = Class.forName("android.view.View$ListenerInfo").getDeclaredField("mOnClickListener")
if (listenerField != null && myLiObject != null) {
    View.OnClickListener myListener = (View.OnClickListener) listenerField.get(myLiObject);
}
```

After that code (I missed a lot of try-catch-blocks), the myListener object holds the instance of the onClickListener, that has been anonymously declared to the view before. It also works with any other listener, just replace the "mOnClickListener parameter" with the one you need in the reflection and cast it correctly.

Note that code changes in upcoming versions can make that not working anymore.

Found the final tutorial here: http://andwise.net/?p=161

Comment: Make sure you call listenerField.setAccessible(true) after you assign listenerField or it wont work!

Answer (score 3):

create classes that implements `OnClickListener`

```
public static class MyClickListener1 implements OnClickListener{
    Activity mActivity;
    MyClickListener1(Acivity activity){
      mActivity=activity;
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
            //do something
    }
}

public static class MyClickListener2 implements OnClickListener{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
            //do something
    }
}
```

and in your code you can easily use them:

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new MyClickListener1(this));
btn.setOnClickListener(new MyClickListener2());
```

or you can create instances and reuse them:

```
OnClickListener listener1 = new MyClickListener1(this);
OnClickListener listener2 = new MyClickListener2();
btn.setOnClickListener(listener1);
btn.setOnClickListener(listener2);
```

you can also define a constructor to pass whatever you need in these classes. I usually pass the activity like in `MyClickListener1`

**EDIT:** If you want to have the listener like object in the button, you can use the tag.

```
btn.setTag(listener1);
btn.setOnClickListener(listener1);
```

and then to get it use

```
OnClickListener old_listener = (OnClickListenr)btn.getTag();
```

Comment: I missed that the custom listener still replaces the old one with that. So in your example `listener2` always replaces `listener1`. Would be great if the old one would still be there, because I have no influence to the source code of where the first listener is assigned. I only get the views with instrumentation.
So there exists no "magic" to get back a listener, when I did not save it on creation?

Comment: That's pretty cool, didn't know that :)
But unfortunately it does not work in my case I have no possibility to save the listener on assignment. I need to get it backwards from the view component. I can see that the mListenerInfo property is set in debug mode, but have no access :(
When a listener is assigned to a button (I can't save it), I need to get the listener back AFTER the assignment.. That's the tricky point. My service must work on different apps (without code-modification), that's why I can't save the listener on assignment or store it in the Tag.

Comment: i found interesting article about access the hidden API: https://devmaze.wordpress.com/2011/01/18/using-com-android-internal-part-1-introduction/ . Hope this can help, I have no time right now, but it looks really interesting.

Comment: The hidden API was a great hint, found a solution. I'll post it and mark it as the answer. Thank you very much, you helped me a lot, mihail

Comment: To achieve something like this you would have to implement the Composite pattern and add all the listeners you want to get triggered at once.

Answer (score 0):

Make two instances of OnCLickListener and assign first or second to button:

```
    Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button1);

    OnClickListener listener_new =  new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d("APP", "NEW CLICK LISTENER ACTIVE");
        }
    };

    OnClickListener listener_old =  new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d("APP", "OLD CLICK LISTENER ACTIVE");
        }
    };

    //setting listener
    b.setOnClickListener(listener_old);
    b.callOnClick();

            //changing listener
    b.setOnClickListener(listener_new);
    b.callOnClick();

            //return your old listener!
        b.setOnClickListener(listener_old);
        b.callOnClick();
```

ADDED:

OnClickListener is protected field of Button class, inherited from View class. Name of the field "mOnClickListener". I can't get it even through reflection.

```
void getListener(Button b) {
java.lang.reflect.Field field =  getClass().getSuperclass().getSuperclass().getDeclaredField("mOnClickListener");
}
```

So You can't get existing listener of the Button if You don't have access to code where it created.

But if You have access to objects of Activity (and we know You have because setting new listener to button), You could add your button with your listener on that activity. Make existing button invisible. And than rollback when necessary.

Comment: Thanks, but it does not work for me, because I have no access to the app, where the listener is assigned. I need the listener from behind with instrumentation. With that I can get the buttons, views and so on but I also need their listeners to restore them after instrumentation. Else when my instrumentation is done, the app would not be controllable anymore.

Answer (score 0):

```
public abstract class ReflectionUtils {

    private static final String listenerInfoFieldName = "mListenerInfo";
    private static final String onCLickListenerFieldName = "mOnClickListener";

    public static OnClickListener getOnClickListener(View view){
        Object listenerInfo = ReflectionUtils.getValueFromObject(view, listenerInfoFieldName, Object.class);
        return ReflectionUtils.getValueFromObject(listenerInfo, onCLickListenerFieldName, View.OnClickListener.class);
    }

    public static <T> T getValueFromObject(Object object, String fieldName, Class<T> returnClazz){
        return getValueFromObject(object, object.getClass(), fieldName, returnClazz);
    }

    private static <T> T getValueFromObject(Object object, Class<?> declaredFieldClass, String fieldName, Class<T> returnClazz){
        try {
            Field field = declaredFieldClass.getDeclaredField(fieldName);
            field.setAccessible(true);
            Object value = field.get(object);
            return returnClazz.cast(value);
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
            Class<?> superClass = declaredFieldClass.getSuperclass();
            if(superClass != null){
                return getValueFromObject(object, superClass, fieldName, returnClazz);
            }
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

Calling `OnClickListener onClickListener = ReflectionUtils.getOnClickListener(myView);` on `myView` will give you the `myView`'s listener that you are looking for.